cut corner with border
I want to resolve an issue with my corner. As depicted in the image, the corner is cut perfectly; however, this is not the case when I zoom in or out on the page.


As you can observe, borders have begun to appear on all sides of the element, which somewhat disrupts the entire layout.
tried a lot of variants, copied code from codepen, other Stackoverflow issues, but couldn't get it to work.
here's the code:


.cut-corner::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid $color_1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cut-corner::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 84%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 6px;
  background-color: #5bd9ab;
  transform: rotate(33deg);
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<div class="btn btn-primary cut-corner position-relative">Edit</div>




https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/#4

@TemaniAfif i copied the provided code, but since my button isn't perfect rectangle i get weird results . ( https://prnt.sc/WtmYXDqvPwwP )

I came out with this, which seems to be fine when zommed out. This uses a clip-path, and an after element. The after element is mainly here to deal with the borders (borders doesn't follow the clip-path)


#bg {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0 , 100% 0, 100% 20%, 80% 100% ,0 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}


#bg:after {
clip-path: polygon(0 0 , 100% 0, 100% calc(20% - 2px), 80% 100% ,0 100%);
  inset: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
}
<div id="bg">
    Some text
</div>




that seems to work fine until i remove the width/height dimensions, then i get something like this : https://prnt.sc/arIZ60Abvi0w . where the corner seems to be distorted

yea i did some magic on this corner (it is the one with the calc) I don't really know what's going on there.  may dive into it tomorow, i'm too busy today
